# Does "aaa accounting commands" not support radius?

Tags: cisco, radius, tacacs+, aaa

When I issue this command:

```
aaa accounting commands 15 default start-stop group myradiusgroup
```

I get this error:
%AAAA-4-SERVNOTACPLUS: The server-group "myradiusgroup" is not a tacacs+ server group. Please define "myradiusgroup" as a tacacs+ server group.

No where in the documentation could I find anything saying the "commmands" accounting type is only available to tacacs+. Does aaa not support this accounting type for radius?

Answer (score 0):

Radius is only used as an an authentication protocol with Cisco when matching against user accounts. TACACS+ is the full AAA protocol suite. Further more, if want to accounting of the commands that a user is sending to the Cisco device your will need setup a tacacs+ server.